# next and previous month from a given month in php

Tags: php, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is best solution to get next and previous month from given date php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8998369/what-is-best-solution-to-get-next-and-previous-month-from-given-date-php)

I am developing a work in php. Here I want to get next and previous month from a given month for example:

`$mth="December"`

I want to display next and previous of December

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$mth="December";
$next_mth = Date("F", strtotime($mth . " next month"));
$pre_mth = Date("F", strtotime($mth . " last month"));
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->modify('+ 1 month');
print $date->format("F"); // next
$date->modify('- 2 month'); 
print $date->format("F"); // previously
```

Answer (score 0):

**Check this out this too a way to get those stuffs**

```
  $mth="December";

$nxt = date('F',mktime(0,0,0,date("m", strtotime($mth))+2,null,null));
$pre = date('F',mktime(0,0,0,date("m", strtotime($mth))-0,null,null));
echo $pre.'-'.$mth.'-'.$nxt;
```