# how can i get previous month name in php

Tags: php, string, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [next and previous month from a given month in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172035/next-and-previous-month-from-a-given-month-in-php)

I use this code :

```
$prev_month = strtolower(date('F',strtotime('February - 1 month')));
```

and always return December even i change the month into March.

Please help!

Comment: Strange it works fine for me

Comment: yes, it's also works fine in my localhost. but in another server, it's return always December. but it's solved with @MrCode now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [next and previous month from a given month in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172035/next-and-previous-month-from-a-given-month-in-php) or [What is best solution to get next and previous month from given date php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8998369/what-is-best-solution-to-get-next-and-previous-month-from-given-date-php) - The question and answer already existed on this website. Please do more search next time.

Comment: Adding my solution: `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE'); $lastmonth = strftime('%B %G', strtotime('last month'));` would give "August 2015" in recent month Sep. 2015.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
$currentMonth = date('F');
echo Date('F', strtotime($currentMonth . " last month"));
```

If you don't want it relative to the current month then set:

```
$currentMonth = 'February';
// outputs January
```

Comment: What if `$currentMonth = 'January'`?

Answer (score 2):

`strtotime()` understand `'last month'`.

```
$last_month = date('F', strtotime('last month'));
```

You can also use the [`\DateTime`](http://php.net/datetime) class:

```
$date_time = new \DateTime('last month');
$last_month = $date_time->format('F');
```

It depends on what you need. If you only want the name of the previous month then the first example is fine. If you want to play with the dates (such as loop over the months in the year) then the `\DateTime` class makes that really easy.

Answer (score 1):

use this code

```
$submonth = date("F", strtotime ( '-1 month' , strtotime ( 'February' ) )) ;
echo $submonth;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use the following code:**

```
echo date("F", time()-date("j")*24*60*60);
```

You can also use:

```
echo date("F", strtotime("last month"));
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP CODE

```
 $days_passed_this_month = date("j");

    $timestamp_last_month = time() - $days_passed_this_month *24*60*60;

    $last_month = date("F", $timestamp_last_month);
```

just play around with the date() and time() functions and see where you get.