# PHP echo the name of the previous month e.g. June

Tags: php, date

Currently I'm using `<?php echo date('F', strtotime('-1 month')); ?>`, which has been working fine but today it the 31st of July, but there are only 30 days in June.

For some reason `echo date('F', strtotime('-1 month'))`
and `echo date('F')` return the same month e.g. July. Then `echo date('F', strtotime('-2 month'))` and `echo date('F', strtotime('-3 month'))` return May and so on.

Comment: We get these questions at the end of every month

Comment: Can't understand why people spend more time writing the answer instead of looking on Google : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889758/getting-last-months-date-in-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can i get previous month name in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13933825/how-can-i-get-previous-month-name-in-php)

Comment: Be careful of the "- 1 month" construct.  It makes sense some of the time and other times it does not.  The meaning of "month" is ambiguous - some have more days than others.  You will get good results if you normalize today's date to the first day of the current month, then subtract one day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this. This will give you previous Month Name

```
<?php

  $pp = date('m', strtotime(date('Y-m')." -1 month"));
  echo date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $pp, 10));
?>
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Other solutions, even linked in the thread don't give a solution for an arbitrary month. This has month or month name which is perfect.

Comment: Sorry, I had to wait 10 mins

Answer (score 1):

This should work no matter how many days there are in the month.

```html
<?php // demo/temp_grs.php
/**
 * Previous Month
 *
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45421749/php-echo-the-name-of-the-previous-month-e-g-june
 */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo '<pre>';


$start = date('Y-m-1') . '- 1 day';
$month = date('F', strtotime($start));
echo $month;
```